# Multi-line elements in JSON?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I would like to use JSON for sending multiple variables like status, error-message and content to a Javascript function via Ajax.

The problem I'm having is that I fetch the content from a database and almost all data that is sent back to the browser is multi-line. And because of that it seems like my JSON is not validated.

An example of outout might be:

```
{
    "status" : "ok",
    "message" : "All is well",
    "contents" : "Lorem Ipsum

    Dolor sit amet"
}
```

Is there any special way of handling multi-line that I've missed or is it plain impossible (seems unlikely)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are control characters, you can't have literal new lines in JSON strings.

See the spec: http://json.org/

New lines are represented as `\n`, but you shouldn't need to worry about that, because your JSON encoding library should take care of that for you. Since it isn't you either have a library with a bug (in which case I suggest fixing it, reporting it, or looking for an alternative) or you aren't using a library (in which case – get one).

Comment: Aha, just found out PHP had one built in, works like a charm :) `json_encode($associative_array)`...